# In Ready Player One, how could Parzival talk to everybody?

Tags: plot-explanation, ready-player-one

Parzival gives a stirring speech that everybody across The Oasis can hear and watch. I didn't notice an explanation of how he reaches (seemingly) every screen and speaker in the Oasis. If that kind of tech is possible, then it seems as though advertisers would be using it all the time.

**How did Parzival accomplish that?** Did Aech hack something? Was it one of the power-ups that Parzival bought? Is this tech always available, but rarely used?

Comment: Have you ever heard of online game sharing like twitch, so if one guy watches and then shares it. and Parzival was listed on top in score board. Popular gamers has fan that watch their game play.

Comment: Most MMO have a "All" or "General Channel", that anybody can use but is usually moderated. Given the fact that there is nobody to moderate or silence him at this point of the movie...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are indications in the book that there is a common communications channel, as well as a linked pa/speaker type system. Add to that, there was very extensive media coverage, due to Parzival's 36 hour media blitz before the assault.

During the arrival to the battle at Castle Anorak, the relevant passage from the book is

> A cloud of smaller ships quickly formed around me, piloted by curious avatars zooming in for a closer look at Leapordon. I had to mute my comlink because so many different people were trying to hail me, asking who the hell I was and where I'd picked up such a sweet ride.

Once they land, there are thousands of avatars already on the ground around the shield:

> When I got closer, I spotted an open patch of ground directly in front of the castle's entrance, just outside the shield wall. Three giant figures stood side by side at the center of the clearing. The crowd around them was continuously surging inward and then receding as avatars pushed back against each other to try to keep respectful distance from Aech, Art3mis and Shoto, who each sat inside their own gleaming giant robot.

The most relevant, however, is when Sorrento (Head Sixer) addresses the group just before the shield drops

> Sorrento surveyed the scene, them smiled up at us. When he spoke, his voice was amplified through powerful speakers mounted on the Sixer gunships and hover tanks, allowing him to be heard by everyone in the area. And since there were cameras and reporters from every major newsfeed outlet present, I knew his words were being broadcast to the entire world.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @Rafee: I thought that Parzival was broadcasting the message to his followers and because he was the top Gunter and his message was so important, it was being re-broadcast and linked to by so many others that it appeared to be on every screen.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. As a filmmaker myself, to show that everyone had switched to Parzival's message, I would have shown a screen that was showing something else, and have someone switch it over to see Parzival.

Comment: Yes.  In the book, everyone can have their own YouTube/Twitch/whatever streams that fans subscribe to. The top gunters would have had almost everyone in the Oasis watching their streams toward this point in the plot.  Obviously, anything important would be re-broadcast by news feeds within seconds...

Comment: @Snow Correct - there's a passage in the movie where Parzival is swooning over Art3mis, saying that he's watching all her streams, IIRC.